# VS 2010 cannot see SQL Server 2012 Express

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-8, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-express

On my PC with Windows 8 there is Visual Studio 2012, SQL Server 2012 Express (x64), SQL Server 2012 (x64).

Visual Studio 2012 works perfectly with SQL Server 2012 Express and SQL Server 2012. It easily adds `sqlexpress` to data connections of server explorer by name `.\SQLEXPRESS`.

But now I'm trying to add `SQLEXPRESS` in Visual Studio 2010. But it cannot find it.

I thought it couldn't because of version of SQL Server 2012 Express. So I've tried to install `SQLEXPR_x64_ENU` (SQL Server 2008 Express), but installation stacks on "Setup Support Rules". There appears error "Performance counter registry hive consistency"

I don't know should and can I install SQL Server 2008 Express. Or the solution is somewhere else?

P.S. When I'm trying to add SQL Database Server to `App_Data` (asp.net mvc3) there is an error "Connections to SQL Server database files (`.mdf`) require SQL Server 2005 Express or SQL Server 2008 Express to be installed and running on the local computer..."

So I think I should edit register of Windows to let know Visual Studio 2010 where SQL Server Express is situated...

What are your suggestions?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want to do. Why are you talking about SQL Server versions 2008 and 2005 at all? I thought you're interested in SQL Server 2012 Express...? Please edit your question and remove all that's irrelevant for your goal & for the actual question.

Comment: Note that when you have several SQL Server versions installed, they cannot all share the same instance name (i.e. only one server instance can be named `SQLEXPRESS`). You can set the name for an instance during setup.

Comment: My goal is to connect from vs2010 to express 2012. I've written anything about sql server 2008 and 2005. i just wrote an error message which says to install express 2008 or 2005

Answer (score 0):

Did you install Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1 prior to installing SQL Server Express 2012 (or at all)?  See this article: http://www.formatyourbrain.com/sql-server-express-2012-visual-studio-2010/